# Update BLE Device Name with the device_name Characteristic Best Practice

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, device-name

What is the best practice for using the Bluetooth Low Energy Generic Access Profile Service (0x1800)?

Is there a reason that iOS prevents developers from using the Generic Access Profile Services and Characteristics?

> Section 3.12 (page 24) documents the fact iOS does not
>   let a developer use that Service (and a couple others)
>   https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

I've also seen some hardware implementations on microcontrollers that also seem to hide this Service from a developer in the firmware.

The work around that I (and most others) have done to allow an app to update the device_name to is to make a separate custom Service-Characteristic that updates the local device name and updates the name in the advertising packet. This is not ideal for many reasons and I am wondering if I am missing something. Should we all be able to use the 0x2A00 Characteristic just like any other Characteristic?